# What is wrong with this append func in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

My Struct Definitions.

```
typedef struct inner_list {char word[100]; inner_list*next;} inner_list;
typedef struct outer_list
{ char word [100];
inner_list * head;
outer_list * next; } outer_list;
```

And The problem part:

```
void append(outer_list **q,char num[100],inner_list *p)
{    outer_list *temp,*r;
     temp = *q;

     char *str;
     if(*q==NULL)
     {   temp = (outer_list *)malloc(sizeof(outer_list));
          strcpy(temp->word,num);
          temp->head = p;
          temp->next=NULL;
          *q=temp;
     }
     else
     {  temp = *q;
         while(temp->next !=NULL)
         {  temp=temp->next;
         }
         r = (outer_list *)malloc(sizeof(outer_list));
         strcpy(r->word,num);
         temp->head = p;
         r->next=NULL;
         temp->next=r;
     }
}
```

I don't know what is i'm doing wrong in this append function i'm sending a char array and a linked list to be stored another linked list. But i can't store the linked list in another linked list. I couldn't figure out the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably explain what you expect this code to do and what the problem is.

Comment: You should probably also officially accept the answer, so as to reward the efforts of your helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the else clause, where your code says

```
temp->head = p;
```

It should say:

```
r->head = p;
```

`r` is the newly created node, so you want to set that node's `head`. What you are doing instead is overwriting an existing node's `head` field.

Comment: perfect man. I must be blind or sth. Thanks so much. 8 hours coding made me blind i guess :D. Thanks so much